# Formula field for getting a first and last word from the string

Tags: formula, formula-field

i need a help with a formula.
I want to create a formula that will select the firts name and the two last names and input them in a box. ps: i m portuguese and we have a lot of family names thats why i need this
Imagine:

First Name: Tomas
Last Name: ferraz amorim silverio montenegro

And the result like this Tomas Ferraz Montenegro

And the name can t excess a max of 27 caracters

Thank you very much

Comment: how are these last names stored currently in your org ? in one field for everything ?

Comment: i m using the standard fields First Name and Last Name , and its the user who fill up the fields

Comment: So are you looking to grab the first and last 'last names' from the last name field only?  In your example there are 4 last names.  Will you always be using the first and last from this field in the formula field?

Comment: I would like to grab always the name in the fiel "First Name" and from the field "Last Name" i want always the firts and the last names in this field(like in the example, i only want ferraz and montenegro) but in this field it can appear 2 , 3 , 5 .... "last names" but i only want the nº1 and the last

Comment: i newbie in salesforce, so i m more looking for info... i thinking abou a formula that count the number of namea and give the first and last, mas i don t know if that is even possible

Comment: @TomasQ. Will there we always space between various last names ?

Comment: What is the logic behind using the last word in the last name field?  What if the first name is 28 characters, you wont be able to store any of the last name anyways.  Why is the max 27 characters that is unreasonably short and that is your real problem here I think.  Why not just chop the concatenation of the names at 27 characters and call it good?

Comment: @PhilR The thing here, is that i need this name with this size, because in the future this "short name" it will be needed to print card an give to the different clients. Probably there is no one with a first name with 27 caracters. so far a have this solution  FirstName & " " &LEFT(LastName,FIND(" ",LastName,1)-1) &RIGHT(LastName,FIND(" ",LastName,1)-1) and now i need to make sure that the name doesn t have more than 27 characters(space is counting has one) and if it has more than 27c i need to short the firts name of the last name field.

Comment: Example:
First Name: Humberto
Last name:Alvarancademo ferraz Ribeiro Queirossa  (imagine that the combine three names Humberto Alvarancademo Queirossa=>27)

Output: Humberto A. Queirossa

Answer (score 6):

I think you should take a look at Salesforce's [Formula Operators and Functions](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US), and especially at the [text Functions](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US#text_functions). I am not even sure it will be possible in you case but you can try it anyways:

> **[FIND](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#FIND):** Returns the position of a string within a string of text represented
> as a number.
>
> **[LEFT](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEFT):** Returns the specified number of characters from the beginning of a
> text string.
>
> **[RIGHT](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#RIGHT):** Returns the specified number of characters from the beginning of a
> text string.

The only formula i can imagine for your case compares the trimmed and untrimmed name string to get the number of the words in the whole string. And then search for the last blank. Unfortunately we can't create a full dynamic formula (i can't find a way to search the string from the right side), in my example this will work with up to 7 words in the name string (you can try to expand this formula):

```
First_Name__c & ' ' & LEFT(Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)) & ' ' &
CASE( LEN(Last_Name__c) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Last_Name__c,' ', '')),
1, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)),
2, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)+1)),
3, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)+1)+1) ),
4, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)+1)+1)+1) ),
5, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)+1)+1)+1)+1) ),
6, RIGHT(Last_Name__c, LEN(Last_Name__c) - FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c, FIND(" ", Last_Name__c)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1) ),
Last_Name__c
)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer !I will work on same and see if something can be done better :) but thanks for your time here

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a space always between different last names ,the below formula can be used to start with

any parsing of string  in formula field can be done via FIND ,LEFT,RIGHT,LEN functions

Here is the partial correct formula for your requirement ,although last part with right function is not correct as FIND takes first space ,we need to find an algorithm to just get the right most characters before space,but something to help you start

```
FirstName+" "+LEFT(LastName,(FIND(" ",LastName)))+" "+RIGHT(LastName,(FIND(" ",LastName)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a correct formula. If the Name is for example `Ferraz Amorim Silverio Montenegro` then this formula gives `Ferraz tenegro`. This is because the FIND function searches always from left to right.

Comment: Agreed @mast0r .But this should give an idea to start thinking along same lines .I am busy but will correct this for sure

Comment: Agree with you in this case ;)

Comment: Thank´s @MohithKumar i tried this formula , and it´s not working perfectly, but it can give me some idea.

Comment: @TomasQ. We will figure this up with exact formula ,no worries .I am busy will post solution if i get free time to work on this

Comment: @TomasQ. I explored this in my free time and i think you can go via trigger to keep the code simpler .trigger would be handy and dynamic code is possible